# Why the input-group-addon Bootstrap class don't work for Span + dropdown?

Tags: css, dropdown

I'm trying to make a "label + combobox" input group using the class input-group to group a span and a select, but, unlike the other components I've tried to group, the width of the span is way bigger than I was expecting. What am I doing wrong ?

Code example:

> ```
> <div class="row" id="entradaDadosExameRegiao"> 
>     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-offset-3" >
>         <div class="input-group" id="dataPreferencia">
>             <span class="input-group-addon">Data de Preferência</span>
>             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
>         </div>    
>     </div>
>     <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5" >
>         <div class="input-group" id="regiaoAgenda">
>             <span id="labelRegiaoAgenda" class="input-group-addon">Região</span>
>             <select id="entradaRegiaoAgenda" class="selectpicker">
>                 <option>Botafogo</option>
>                 <option>Copacabana</option>
>                 <option>Icarai</option>
>                 <option>Icaraiajdijwadioawmjdioawdioawd</option>
>             </select>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

[image]

I've also tried to force the width, but it didn't worked:

> ```
>         #labelRegiaoAgenda {
>             witdh: 100px;
>         }
> ```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Check with your browser's dev tools which styles are assigned to the span. Maybe it has `min-width:50%` or something.

Comment: But there's anyway I can make it work o firefox without changing this "default" value ? (I've tested on IE, Firefox and Chrome. The width value only works on IE)

Comment: If `width` works only on IE and not on other browsers, there are other things going wrong. Because `width` is supposed to work the same way on all browsers! So is there a syntax error earlier in the CSS, that may cause the parser to get confused? (Syntax errors will make different browsers behave differently!) Do you have an error in your DOCTYPE declaration, causing the document to be switched to quirks mode? (Different browsers have different quirks!) Etc. Run your page through the W3C validator.